# OSGi Runtime cannot be loaded: In eclipse

Tags: eclipse, osgi, predix

I am trying to create new Image Discription for my prdix machine and I am getting following error in Eclipse.

> OSGi Runtime cannot be loaded: Directory:
>   /home/shubham/.eclipse....v20161214/runtime does not contain a valid
>   product installation

I am getting following error in eclipse as shown in [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DQ16.png) when I click over Predix Machine Icon. It is giving runtime can not be loaded.

There is no such user Shubham in my system and Home folder does not contain shubham folder. I am using;
 - CentOS7
 - eclipse neon 4.6.2
 - Predix Machine 16.4.0
 - java1.8

Comment: In order for the community to help you it would be a good idea to review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and add a few more details about what you are trying to accomplish and what you already have or have not tried.  For instance, what version of Eclipse?  What did you select as your image description?  Are you following a specific tutorial that has more context?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here.

Comment: I have edited my question, please see again and help me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this. I was using old eclipse workspace which was copied form different system, that is why it was using old settings and was searching for folder which is not there.